# Using JMX Exporter on Kafka Connect Confluent image throw a NoSuchFieldException at agent loading time

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, jmx-exporter

I'm currently triying to expose Kafka Connect Workers JMX :

Using this docker image :

```
FROM cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.5.3-7.1.0
ADD --chown=1000:1000 exporterConfig.yml /opt/prometheus-exporter/prom-jmx-agent-config.yml
ADD --chown=1000:1000 jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.17.0.jar /opt/prometheus-exporter/agent.jar
```

The JMX Exporter version is the last one from 0

Here is the result logs when the connect worker is starting :

```
PS D:\env\confluent-platform> docker logs connect -f
===> User
uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)
===> Configuring ...
===> Running preflight checks ...
===> Check if Kafka is healthy ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: UNKNOWN
        at io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector$Rule.<init>(JmxCollector.java:57)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector.loadConfig(JmxCollector.java:214)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector.<init>(JmxCollector.java:91)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.JavaAgent.premain(JavaAgent.java:29)
        ... 6 more
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 422
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed
```

This java.lang.NoSuchFieldError make me think about dependency conflict issue,

I got through the code of JMX Exporter & its simpleclient [dependency](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java)

indeed the UNKNOWN Type enum value from simpleclient dependency in Collector.java class only appeared after version 10, and 14 is the dependency version number in JMX Exporter.

But i took the source code of the cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen and i was not able to find any reference to this dependency package.

Any advice welcome !

Answer (score 2):

If you check the source code of the
[confluent kafka-connect images](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-images/blob/master/kafka-connect-base/include/etc/confluent/docker/launch)

You will notice that, you have to set the following environment variables to enable JMX

1. KAFKA_JMX_OPTS
2. KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME (optional, if not specified it will take the current hostname)
3. KAFKA_JMX_PORT

The issue you are facing is because when you specify the `KAFKA_JMX_OPTS`, by default the jmx authentication is `enabled`. To disable it use this flag `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false`

I resolved this issue with following configuration:

```
  KAFKA_JMX_OPTS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-sample/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.17.2.jar=8080:/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-sample/prometheus-kafka-connect.yml -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```